¿Cómo soluciono este problema de CocoaPods, en la creación de un proyecto en ReactNative?
He seguido la guía de descarga de ReactNative, pero después de instalar todo, ahora al crear un proyecto me da erro el CocoaPods (aunque lo tengo instalado).
Aquí lo que he descargado.
brew install node
brew install watchman
--->Xcode
sudo gem install cocoapods

He ejecutado -->
 npx react-native@latest init ProyectoUNO
                                                          
               ######                ######               
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
             ##  ########################  ##             
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
 ##             ###     ##########     ###             ## 
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
             ##  ########################  ##             
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
               ######                ######               
                                                          

                  Welcome to React Native!                
                 Learn once, write anywhere               

⠸ Downloading templat eerror Installing pods failed. This doesn't affect project initialization and you can safely proceed. 
However, you will need to install pods manually when running iOS, follow additional steps in "Run instructions for iOS" section.

✖ Downloading template


info  To enable automatic CocoaPods installation when building for iOS you can create react-native.config.js with automaticPodsInstallation field. 
For more details, see https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/projects.md#projectiosautomaticpodsinstallation
            
✖ Could not create an empty Git repository, see debug logs with --verbose

  
  Run instructions for Android:
    • Have an Android emulator running (quickest way to get started), or a device connected.
    • cd "/Users/miquelarnaublasco/ProyectoUNO" && npx react-native run-android
  
  Run instructions for iOS:
    • cd "/Users/miquelarnaublasco/ProyectoUNO/ios"
    
    • Install Cocoapods
      • bundle install # you need to run this only once in your project.
      • bundle exec pod install
      • cd ..
    
    • npx react-native run-ios
    - or -
    • Open ProyectoUNO/ios/ProyectoUNO.xcodeproj in Xcode or run "xed -b ios"
    • Hit the Run button
    
  Run instructions for macOS:
    • See https://aka.ms/ReactNativeGuideMacOS for the latest up-to-date instructions.

